# How to add components in a stream using cleartool commands?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I want to add components to a stream (development and integration) in clearcase. How do I add the components using commands (cleartool) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [cleartool rebase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) should be enough: by rebasing a component baseline, that would add the component automatically to the stream.
Execute that in a dynamic view (faster than a snapshot view)

The related commands are:

[`cleartool chstream`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chstream.htm), that you can use to:

- [recommend baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29239953/6309).
- [*remove* a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548082/6309) (but that is not your case)

And [cleartool chproject](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chproject.htm), used to [to convert non modifiable baseline to modifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427967/6309).

---

To add *multiple* baselines, assuming you don't have a [composite baseline through a rootless component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318270/6309) (which could group all those baselines under one), you would have to loop over your different baselines, ad rebase them one by one on your stream.

---

Note that with *one* command, you can list all existing foundation baselines of a stream, as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309):

```
cleartool lsstream -fmt %[found_bls]p -cview
```

That means you can then double-check which baselines are already present (and would not need to be rebased *again*), and which baselines would have to be rebased.

Comment: I tried cleartool rebase, but it only adds one component...not all. How do I add all those components in the stream which is provided as baseline to that which I am creating?

Comment: @Shivani You would need to rebase those baselines one by one: see my edited answer.

Comment: ohh! Isn't there any way wherein we can get all the list of components to be added via a command instead of manually checking all the components present in the baseline stream?

Comment: @Shivani There is one command to get existing baselines already on the stream: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! Been really useful! :)